# Nothing is reachable inside of a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I need to manipulate my buttons etc. inside the fragment but, findViewById method is not recognized. Additionally, even alert dialog can not be set, since methods are not recognized.

If i add getActivity() or getActivity().getApplicationContext() it works for the activity that fragments is binded.

What is the correct way for achieving my object and making operations with them inside the fragment?

Comment: DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),

Answer (score 1):

The `findViewById` method is inherited from the `Activity` class. In a fragment you can call this method on a particular `View` object. In most of the cases you will call it on the inflated view. Take in mind that the `findViewById` is a slow operation!! It is always a good practice to keep the references to your Views as activity memebers. Also call this method on the most concrete `View` object - if you want to take View from a container that is placed in a bigger container, call the method on the smaller one - it is faster. :)

Answer (score 0):

For Example

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_fragment, container, false);
    listView = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    ImageButton imageBtn = (ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    imageBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Builder MyAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                MyAlertDialog.setTitle("Title");
                MyAlertDialog.setMessage("Message");
                DialogInterface.OnClickListener deleteClick = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        //your code
                    }
                };
                MyAlertDialog.setPositiveButton("First",deleteClick );
                MyAlertDialog.setNeutralButton("Second",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                     {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){ 
                            //second
                        }

                     });
                MyAlertDialog.setNegativeButton("Last",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                     {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            return;
                        }
                     });
                MyAlertDialog.show();

        }
        });
    return v;
}
```

Comment: how to use onPrepareDialog() method in a fragment?

Answer (score 0):

For Fragment, you should override onCreateView method and inflate the view you want

```
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_fragment_layout, container, false);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar)root.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
 }
```

Comment: mPickDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
            }
        });

for example; showDialog is not recognized; what to do here?

Comment: rotected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
  switch (id) {
  case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
   return new DatePickerDialog("WHAT TO ADD HERE", mDateSetListener, mYear, mMonth,
     mDay);
  }
  return null;
 }


also what do i need to add "WHAT TO ADD HERE" field to be used in a fragment